# jQuery and If statement to de-select radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well, I'm stuck and have been banging my head for a little while now to try to figure what I'm doing wrong.

Scenario:

I have a question with a Yes/No answer (ie 2 radio buttons). When a user selects the either Yes or No, I call a function to .toggle() a hidden div to show a link. That works great. And if they go back and check that Yes/No again it disappears again due to the .toggle()

My issue is that if a user clicks the No (and the link is shown) but then clicks the Yes I want the link that is showing due to the No result to disappear and vice-versa.

So basically only show 1 link at a time.

I figured that maybe an If statement would work but I can't seem to get it right.

My code:

```
<div id="Question1">
  <div>Do you kazoo?</div>
  <input type="radio" ID="Q1RB1" runat="server" value="Yes" text="Yes" name="RadioGroup1"/>Yes<br />
  <input type="radio" ID="Q1RB2" runat="server" value="No" text="No" name="RadioGroup1"/> No
  <span id="Q1RB1Results" style="display:none">&nbsp; &nbsp; <a href=#>Click here</a></span>  
  <span id="Q1RB2Results" style="display:none">&nbsp; &nbsp; <a href=#>Click here</a></span>
 </div>
```

My jQuery code that works for each individual radio button:

```
    $("input[id$=Q1RB1]:radio").change(function () {
        $("[id$=Q1RB1Results]").toggle();
    });

    $("input[id$=Q1RB2]:radio").change(function () {
        $("[id$=Q1RB2Results]").toggle();

    });
```

This is the If statement I'm trying to get to work. Amy I going about this the wrong way?

```
    if ($("input[id$=Q1RB2]").is(":checked")) {
        $("input[id$=Q1RB2]:radio").change(function () {
            $("[id$=Q1RB2Results]").toggle();
        });
    });
```

Thanks for any thoughts/advice. I've tried a multitude of answers here in Stackoverflow and the 'net but can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. :(
~V

**Update: I put a sample form and the dialogue up on JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Valien/7uN6z/4/** I tried some of the solutions mentioned here and couldn't get them working so not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When you register an event listener in JQuery (.change, .click, .blur, etc.), the Javascript engine matches the selector and applies them at that point. With that in mind, you can rearrange your code (which is close to being right) to this, which should do the trick:

```
/* The function you're about to define applies to all radio button 
   inputs whose ID ends with Q1RB2 */
$("input[id$=Q1RB2]:radio").change(function()
{
    /* Inside the change function, $(this) refers to the instance that
       was changed. So, this checks to see if the instance that was just 
       changed is currently checked, after being changed. */
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
        // If that was the case, then toggle the item
        $("[id$=Q1RB2Results]").toggle();
    }
});
```

Comment: can you explain the the selector in your answer to me I don't understand what it is doing

Comment: I edited my answer to include more of an explanation. Let me know if you still have questions.

Comment: Keep in mind that he's toggling another control, not `$(this)`. Your code is the equivalent of always making the radio be unchecked.

Comment: so the $ in the selector is a wild card I would have thought they would have used "*"

Comment: @Blindy: Thanks for the catch. I edited the answer.
@mcgrailm: $ is the JQuery object. When you call $(stuff), you're passing data to the constructor.

Comment: He means the `$` in `$=`. @mcgrailm, this is the W3C CSS language definition. They use `*=` for contains and `$=` for ends with.

Comment: mcgrailm: Here's a list of all the selectors JQuery supports: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: tried this and it semi-worked. Going to rethink and try again. I was too tired when trying to implement it.

Comment: Programming tired is almost as bad as driving drunk.

Comment: Ok, I just put this in JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Valien/6WmaY/ - it's semi-working so I think the idea is there...now to get it working all the way! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$('input:radio[name=RadioGroup1]').change(function(){
    var show = "#" + $(this).attr('id') + 'Results';
    $('#Question1 span').hide();
    $(show).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you need:

```
// declare common variables so it's easier to target
var question = $("#Question1"),
    group = question.find("input[name='RadioGroup1']"),
    span = question.find("span");

// change listener for each radio button group
group.click(function(){ 
    var id = $(this).attr("id"); // get the radio button id for reference
    span.each(function(){ // loop through each span and check which one to hide/show
        var item = $(this);
        if (item.attr("id")===id+"Results") { item.show(); } else { item.hide(); }
    });
});
```